# C++ #include headers

Tags: c++

there is a C++ book that says that we need to #include a header two times in two different files, one with a class, another with main() that uses the class from the previous file.

Here is the quote :

> because our Sales_data class has a string member, Sales_data.h  must #include the string header. Programs that use Sales_data also need to include the string header.

But there is something I don't understand. If we #include "Sales_data.h" in our main file, #include <(string)> is already in this header so no need to #include <(string)> in our main file.

From what I understand, when we #include a file in a main file, C++ only copy and paste the entirety of the file called with the header in the main file. So adding a second #include <(string)> is unnecessary. I'm talking about what happens when there isn't any #ifndef or #define in the header.

I did the test myself and I only needed to write #include <(string)> in one file and it worked. I isn't any # directive in either file except #pragma once in the header file.

Comment: You typically don't want to rely on which header includes which other headers. If your module uses `std::string`, you `#include <string>`, even if some other header that your module includes also includes string. Headers have include guards for this reason.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to say "before you cross the street you must look both ways" even though it's possible that you can cross the street without looking both ways and not have anything terrible happen. What happens if `Sales_data.h` is later changed to not include `string`?

Comment: technically its not required, but does no harm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description you read is bogus. If the definition of a class C uses a type T, such as `std::string`, then that type needs to be available. Usually (except with Microsoft code) the header that defines C includes the header that defines T. Client code of C then needs only include the header that defines C.

The situation is different with more arbitrary indirect header inclusions. Let's say class C doesn't use `std::string`, but its header includes `<string>`. Then if your code that uses C, also uses `std::string`, it's good practice to let your code also include `<string>`. Even if that's not necessary at the current point of the code's evolution.

The case for client code including the necessary headers, as with at least former Microsoft style, is that it by itself can give faster builds (fewer file accesses during a build), and supports some build optimization via primitive tools such as Visual C++'s precompiled headers, where all headers to be precompiled need to be collected in one big Mother Of All Headers. The case against that practice is that it makes for more work in maintenance. And 80% of all programming is maintenance.

Comment: In addition to PCH, a standard library header might just include an internal header that defines the component it needs rather than the entire thing. I recall seeing a few SO questions about including something that uses `std::string`, but which in MSVC only includes an internal header (`xstring` IIRC) that doesn't define the stream insertion/extraction operators.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the situation where `Sales_data.h` is modified to use a forward deceleration of `std::string` (instead of getting `std::string`'s deceleration from the system header.)   This would allow `Sales_data.c` to compile with `Sales_data.h`, but would then cause compilation errors on any files including `Sales_data.h`, using `std::string`, but not including `<string>`.

You are correct in assuming that you may get this header indirectly from other header files, but it is not something you should rely on.  I believe the author is suggesting it as a best practice.

Comment: The class has a `std::string` data member; it can't use a forward declaration.

Comment: It can in the header if the type is not being used anywhere other than decelerations.  The source would include the header.

Comment: **−1** The claim that a data member can be declared with incomplete type, is incorrect and very misleading in this context.

Comment: I see it done all the time in software, and its one of the tactics illustrated in Large-Scale C++ Software Design by John Lakos. It eliminates dependencies, and decreases compile times.  It's one of the reasons people suggest including what you need and not relying on other header files.

Comment: All of your new claims are false. You may have been mislead by the possibility of using an incomplete type in the declaration of a member function. There its size is not needed. Generally, try to *understand* things instead of memorizing them. That will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking in terms of member functions.  Same logic applies.  If the class no longer needs it as a data member but still has methods that use strings, it could cause problems on a forward declare.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence

> Programs that use Sales_data also need to include the string header.

can be interpreted (with a grain of salt) as pointing out that any program that uses Sales_data does include the string header, because it is included in the Sales_data header.

Of course a class should come with all required headers already included.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the statement is that there are 2 distinct cases which should be distinguished, but the statement lumps them together.

Case 1:

```
// Foo.h
#include <string>
class Foo {
  std::string member;
public:
  Foo() { member = "Hello, world"; }
};
```

Case 2:

```
// Foo.h
#include <string>
class Foo {
public:
  std::string Hi() const { return "Hello, world"; }
};
```

In the first case, the inclusion of `<string>` is an exposed implementation detail. The implementation could probably be changed to use a `std::vector<char>` instead. In the second case, `std::string` is part of the interface of `class Foo`, and no longer is an implementation detail.

In the second case, and **only** in the second case can you rely on `<string>` being included in `"Foo.h"`.

Comment: I like this distinction. But I think that in C++ it's impractical to try to ascertain whether a header included by `Foo.h` is due to case 1 or case 2, so as to derive the benefit of sometimes not including a header. I think the important thing is that with reasonable coding practices one should be able to use `Foo.h` without having to include any supporting headers.